# Play framework controller method that accepts POST

Tags: rest, post, playframework

I did not find a example detailing out the format of a method that accepts post request and a corresponding functional test for the same. Below is what I am doing. The controller method gets null json string value. I looked at the binder option, but I feel the below approach to be easy and trying to make this work. Am I missing something trivial?

play v 1.2.4

routes

```
  /v1/xyzs                  Application.createXyz(format:'json')
```

Controller

```
public static void createXyz(String xyzJson)
{
    Xyz xyz = new Gson().fromJson(xyzJson, Xyz.class);
    Xyz savedXyz = xyz.save();

    render();
}
```

Functional Test

```
@Test
public void createXyzTest()
{
    Xyz xyz = new Xyz("id", 12345, "Summary", "Main");
    String body = new Gson().toJson(xyz);

    Response response = POST("/v1/xyzs", "application/json", body);

    assertStatus(201, response);
}
```

**UPDATE:**
Below code in functional test worked.

```
Xyz xyz = new Xyz("id", 12345, "Summary", "Main");
String body = new Gson().toJson(xyz);

Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String,String>();
params.put("xyzJson", body);
Response response = POST("/v1/xyzs",params);
```

Answer (score 1):

What if `String body = String.format("{\"xyzJson\": %s}", new Gson().toJson(xyz));`

Comment: I added this to my test but the controller is still getting null for xyzJson.

Comment: Looking back, the above code you posted should also have worked. let me try later to confirm